Matrix algebra: Kronecker product and integrals involving exponentials
I have been trying to figure out how the following might work.
For matrices (of conformable dimensions) $A$ and $B$, and an identity matrix $I$, we have
\begin{equation*}
-(A\otimes I+ I\otimes B)^{-1} ~=~\int_0^{\infty}e^{xA}\otimes e^{xB} dx
\end{equation*}
I could not possibly find any reference that might be relevant...

For Google purposes, it may prove useful to note that $A\otimes I+I\otimes B$ is known as a Kronecker sum. So you're looking for an integral representation for the inverse of a Kronecker sum.

If $E$ and $F$ are two finite dimensional linear spaces , if $L$ is the linear space of linear applications $f$ from $E$ to $F$, if $A$ is a linear applcation of $F$ into itself, and if $B$ is a linear application of $E$ into itself, then $A\otimes B$ is the linear application of $L$ into itself defined by $f\mapsto AfB.$ For instance $A\otimes I+I\otimes B$ is the map $f\mapsto Af+fB.$ I dislike the matrix representation by a 'Kronecker product' of this natural algebraic operation.

Just learnt from Gangadharaiah and Sandeep (2021, Chapter 6.3 of Matrix Exponential (page 458)) that this holds via the inverse Laplace transform of matrix exponentials
\begin{equation*}
\int_0^{\infty}e^{-ts}e^{tX}dt = (sI-X)^{-1}
\end{equation*}
Thanks for those who commented above.

To fill in one detail that might not be apparent to future readers: If $X=A\otimes I+I\otimes B$, then $e^X=e^A \otimes e^B$. This $X$, in conjunction with $s=0$, yields of the formula of interest. (Note that the convergence of the above identity usually is hand-waved by taking $s$ to have sufficiently large real part. But in the present case $s=0$, so the formula is only expected to be valid when $X$ is negative-definite.)

Thanks! @Semiclassical

$e^{A\otimes I+I\otimes B}=e^A\otimes e^B$ is a truly elegant formula.

Also in Alexander Graham, Kronecker Products. https://store.doverpublications.com/products/9780486824178  given as Example 2.6 on page 32.
